# How do i test i2c high-z condition?

Tags: fpga, system-verilog, verification, uvm, system-verilog-assertions

I connect i2c signals as tri1 because of pull-up. I want to see i2c signals as high-z, but assertion is failed because of tri1. Know someone who can answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the strength into a string, and do a string compare

```
($sformatf("%v",SDA) == "Pul")
```

This is true when the signal is in the passive pullup state.

Comment: I try to answer and assertion is failed. Then displayed sda line and i saw St1(Strong1).

Comment: Then you have not modeled the i2c signals correctly, It should only be Pu1 or St0.

Comment: Dave, thank you for your help. As I said earlier, in top module I connected i2c dut over tri1 to i2c vip (interface). Scl and sda are wires in the interface. We use questasim and mentor vip suit.